# RethinkDB / horizon: After some usage getting 400 Bad Request Errors resulting in ReqlRuntimeError.ReqlError [as constructor] after restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb, horizon

After using horizon dev server for some time I suddenly get a '400 Bad Request Error'. After restarting the server I get the following error in the terminal:

```
at ReqlRuntimeError.ReqlError [as constructor] (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\errors.js:23:13)
        at new ReqlRuntimeError (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\errors.js:90:51)
        at mkErr (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\util.js:177:10)
        at Feed.IterableResult._addResponse (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\cursor.js:75:27)
        at TcpConnection.<anonymous> (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\net.js:360:22)
        at TcpConnection.cancel (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\util.js:26:16)
        at TcpConnection.cancel (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\net.js:783:43)
        at wrappedCb (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\net.js:270:17)
        at tryCatcher (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
        at Promise.successAdapter (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\nodeify.js:23:30)
        at Promise._settlePromiseAt (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:579:21)
        at Promise._settlePromises (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:697:14)
        at Async._drainQueue (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:123:16)
        at Async._drainQueues (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:133:10)
        at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (c:\Users\carl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\horizon\node_modules\rethinkdb\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:15:14)
        at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

The error gets logged two to three times in a row and then it states:

> ```
> Horizon ready for connections �
> ```

But when reconnecting to the server via 'localhost:8181' it states '400 Bad Request Error' in the console again.

The Admin Interface is showing no issues.

This happens while playing around with the code from the Getting Started Guide on a Win10 64bit machine using Node.js v4.4.4 and horizon v1.0.1.

Comment: Can you try the latest Horizon 1.0.2? This was probably fixed. (Edit: actually the printed error was fixed, the 400 bad request issue might still be there?)

Comment: @DanielMewes I updated to the new version and it seems to work right now. I am not even getting the 400 bad request error. Is there a changelog for horizon, that I can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I updated to horizon v1.0.2 I haven't had the problem anymore. Neither the ReqlRuntimeError nor the 400 Bad Request Error.